# Radius of convergence of this power series?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, absolute-convergence

The coefficient of $(x^2)^n$ is $(n!)^2/(2n)!$. I did the problem and calculated the radius of convergence to be 2. But the book says it's 4. I'm having the same issue with similar problems where only even powers of $x$ are present. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Let $t=x^2$ and do the problem as usual.  Now convert back to $x$'s.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. The radius of convergence for $t$ is 4 and so it should be 2 for $x$ no?

Comment: Right, so if it converges when $-4 < x^2 < 4$ (which is really $0 \leq x^2 < 4$) then it will converge when $-2 < x < 2$ (modulo endpoints).  I tend to agree with you until I see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I think you meant $0≤x^2<4$? Also, I should correct myself. Before letting $t=x^2$ I calculated the radius of convergence and it was 4. When I put $t=x^2$, it can no longer assume negative value.